# MS Graph API demanding Insufficient privileges to complete the operation. Permission is given already

Tags: rest, microsoft-graph-api

I have an office 365 account from work and it is not admin. When I try the Graph API for Planner to get all the plans, It responds with Insufficient privileges to complete the operation. I know that it requires the permission of  "Group.ReadWrite.All". If I ask my boss for this permission, Is it going to be limited to my account only or is it going to make my account an admin which i will not likely get it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Application Registration Portal to get the token:

1. In Application Registration Portal set the permission that you need, for example
   Group.ReadWrite.All and **Directory.AccessAsUser.All**. Always you must use **Directory.AccessAsUser.All** because users need login and get the token.

   2. When save Application Registration Portal go to Azure Portal, in Azure Active Directory --> Enterprise applications --> click in you application --> "click in consent permission for username..." --> login --> accept.
   3. Use librarys as hellojs and get a token.